# How to solve class inheritance in Python?

Tags: python, class, dry

I have 2 almost identical classes. How can they be solved by inheritance?

1 class (maybe parent):

```
class Heart():
    """ třída zdraví """
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.s = []
        self.h = 0

    def vykresli(self):
        #vykreslení srdce
        heart_big = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(DIR, "images/heart_big.png"))
        heart_small = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(DIR, "images/heart_small.png"))
        if random.randrange(0, 500) ==  1 and len(self.x) <= 0:
            self.x.append(random.randrange(50, 970))
            self.y.append(0)
            self.s.append(random.randrange(1, 4))

        for x in range(len(self.x)):
            if self.h % 9 == 0: 
                SCREEN.blit(heart_big, (self.x[x], self.y[x]))
            else:
                SCREEN.blit(heart_small, (self.x[x], self.y[x]))
            self.y[x] += self.s[x]
        self.h += 1
        if self.h > 100: self.h = 0
 
        for y in range(len(self.x)):
            if self.y[y] > OKNO_Y:
                del self.y[y]
                del self.x[y]
                del self.s[y]
                break
```

2 class (maybe child)

```
class MissileStack():
    """definuje třídu nabití zásobníku střelami"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.s = []
        self.h = 0
        self.rotate = 0

    def vykresli(self):
         #vykreslení dodávky zásoby střel
        misilestack = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(DIR, "images/misilestack.png"))
        if random.randrange(0, 50) ==  1 and len(self.x) <= 0:
            self.x.append(random.randrange(50, 970))
            self.y.append(0)
            self.s.append(random.randrange(1, 4))
        #self.missile = pygame.transform.rotate(pygame.image.load(os.path.join(DIR, "images/missile.png")),180)
        for x in range(len(self.x)):
            misilestackrotate = pygame.transform.rotate(misilestack, self.rotate)
            SCREEN.blit(misilestackrotate, (self.x[x], self.y[x]))
            self.y[x] += self.s[x]
        self.h += 1
        self.rotate += 1
        if self.rotate >= 360: self.rotate = 0
        if self.h > 100: self.h = 0
 
        for y in range(len(self.x)):
            if self.y[y] > OKNO_Y:
                del self.y[y]
                del self.x[y]
                del self.s[y]
                break
```

Both classes do practically the same thing. They just use a different image and a different random generation. I've read a lot of tutorials on class inheritance, but I can't use inheritance in practice.

Comment: Start small: factor out similar code into functions

Comment: And yeah, make a base class with all the common code (like `__init__`)

Comment: I usually wait until I have three or more copies of basically the same function/object before I attempt to extract a generic implementation. Else I risk extracting a wrong interface.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev. If you extract small enough pieces, you'll be fine. Looks like you're doing three separate things in your `vykresli` function. Separate those out regardless.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I'm not the OP, but the pieces _can_ be too small. So small they cause more harm than good. Not to mention that coming up with good names is a hard problem.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev. My mistake. On the one hand I agree in general, but on the other hand, your argument does not apply in this particular case.

Comment: One of the steps I'd do is look at the differences (https://www.diffchecker.com/oNPQ6Gi1) and name them (extract as methods, so they can be replaced/overridden). Then name the matching parts too.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: "on the other hand, your argument does not apply in this particular case" - not sure about that. The problem of very small methods is universal and applies everywhere. And the rule of three applies here too, I think. The more variations of the operation we see, the better we know which parts are constant and which can change. Anyhow, we both agree that some methods will need to be extracted.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev. I've added a sample showing how to go about doing it based on the very limited info provided. Really just couldn't resist. It's understood that this is just a first pass to show OP what to look for, and not a realistic analysis.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: yep, I saw that. Great job (giving such limited input).

Comment: I'm really a beginner. My first act in Python is on Github https://github.com/radekjuthner/Invaders
There is probably a lot to improve in the code. I need to gain more experience.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that your code is doing a bunch of questionable things, You can create a base class that factors out the common operations.

All the class and method names are completely made up here, since I don't know what you are really trying to do and my command of your native language is non-existent:

```
class Sprite:
    def __init__(self, r):
        self.x = []
        self.y = []
        self.s = []
        self.r = r

    def vykresli(self):
        if random.randrange(0, self.r) ==  1 and len(self.x) <= 0:
            self.x.append(random.randrange(50, 970))
            self.y.append(0)
            self.s.append(random.randrange(1, 4))

        self.pre_loop()
        for x in range(len(self.x)):
            self.do_blit((self.x[x], self.y[x]))
            self.y[x] += self.s[x]
        self.post_loop()

        for y in range(len(self.x)):
            if self.y[y] > OKNO_Y:
                del self.y[y]
                del self.x[y]
                del self.s[y]
                break

    def pre_loop(self):
        pass

    def post_loop(self):
        pass
```

The deltas now make for two small specific classes:

```
class Heart(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(500)
        self.h = 0
        #vykreslení srdce
         self.heart_big = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(DIR, "images/heart_big.png"))
         self.heart_small = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(DIR, "images/heart_small.png"))

    def do_blit(self, coord):
        if self.h % 9 == 0: 
            SCREEN.blit(self.heart_big, coord)
        else:
            SCREEN.blit(self.heart_small, coord)

    def post_loop(self):
        super().post_loop()
        self.h += 1
        if self.h > 100:
            self.h = 0
```

and

```
class Missiles(Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(50)
        #vykreslení dodávky zásoby střel
        misilestack = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(DIR, "images/misilestack.png"))

    def pre_loop(self):
        super().pre_loop()
        self.misilestackrotate = pygame.transform.rotate(misilestack, self.rotate)

    def do_blit(self, coord):
        SCREEN.blit(self.misilestackrotate, coord)

    def post_loop(self):
        super().post_loop()
        self.rotate += 1
        if self.rotate >= 360:
            self.rotate = 0
```

I've added hooks called `pre_loop`, `do_blit` and `post_loop` to allow you to do class-specific operations for each type of `Sprite`. You can experiment with abstract base classes if you want to do things like enforce an implementation of `do_blit`.